# Python+OOP - Adding attributes and creating Game Object

Tags: python, oop, console-application

Hi i would like to know if i have added the sword and axe to my objects correctly?
I would like to make my character move +2 forward when attacking and -2 backward when defending. Is my code for def move correct?

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VBvy.jpg)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V62u.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inheritance and write something like that:

```
class Item:

    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name


class Character:
    def __init__(self, weapon: Item) -> None:
        self.weapon = weapon


class Warrior(Character):
    def __init__(self, weapon: Item) -> None:
        # some attributes
        super().__init__(weapon=weapon)


class Tanker(Character):
    def __init__(self, weapon: Item) -> None:
        # some attributes
        super().__init__(weapon=weapon)


sword = Item(name="Sword")
axe = Item(name="Axe")
warrior = Warrior(weapon=sword)
tanker = Tanker(weapon=axe)
```